# Remote syslog config does not work

Tags: linux, networking, debian, rsyslog

I'm trying to redirect my syslog to a server located in 192.168.56.5.

In the first machine(not the server) I added this line to rsyslog.conf

```
local0.info    @@192.168.56.5
```

Then in the server machine I changed the first lines to allow UDP connection by removing the '#' from

```
$ModLoad imupd
$UPDServerRun 514
```

Then added the line

```
local0.info    /var/log/monitorizacion
```

If I run `logger -n 192.168.56.5 -p local0.info "msg"` it works and adds a line to `/var/log/monitorizacion` but if I only do `logger -p local0.info "msg"`, that should work exactly as the previous command, does not work.

Why is this happening?

EDIT: Debian OS: debian-8.3.0-i386
Rsyslog: rsyslogd 8.4.2

Comment: Could you please update question with OS distribution version and syslog version ?

Comment: @ShubhangiPardeshi done!

Answer (score 0):

You may have misspelt the directive, I think it should be:

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
```

However, since you said that all you did was remove the `#` from rsyslog.conf, it's possible that your rsyslog.conf file is correct, and you just misspelt it here?

Might as well include the port too, but I *think* the way you have it is fine as the default UDP port is 514.  Also, try a single `@` instead of `@@`.  I believe the first is for UDP while the latter is for TCP:

```
local0.info    @192.168.56.5:514
```

Also, I'd restart the rsyslog service on both machines to be safe after you change the configuration files.  If neither of these help, please update your question and be specific on what machines each logger command is run from.  I'm not sure how that first logger command you wrote works:

```
logger -n 192.168.56.5 -p local0.info -p "msg"
```

I don't think that second `-p` should be there, as "msg" is not a priority.

Comment: My bad, that second -p is a typo, sorry for the confussion.

The rest has been taken care of but unfortunately it does not resolve it :(

Comment: @dari1495 Hey no problem.  I edited my answer, so try a single `@` instead for UDP.  And like always, it's a good idea to restart the rsyslog service.